# Can not figure out how to access elements of a specific child

Tags: php, xml, xpath

I am using simpleXML and php.  I am trying to have my page access a specific child element based on the value of a different child element.  I am very confused as to how to do this without looping through every child of a specific parent.  I tried doing this with xpath, but I can not figure out the proper format.  My XML is:

```
<vendor>
  <vendor_id>6</vendor_id>
     <name>Store</name>
       <stock>
          <stock_id>4</stock_id>
          <stock_url>http://www.url.com/item.php</stock_url>
       </stock>
       <stock>
           <stock_id>9</stock_id>
           <stock_url>http://www.url.com/items.php</stock_url>
       </stock>
    </vendor>
```

I want to access the stock_url of a specific stock ID.  Is this possible, or do I need to loop through every instance of stock and do a comparison to find the one I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($string); // <-- assuming the XMl you mentioned above is in $string
$stock_id = 9;
$result = $xml->xpath('/vendor/stock[stock_id='.$stock_id.']');
if(!empty($result)) $url = $result[0]->stock_url;
```

Comment: It works perfect!  And much easier than I was making it out to be.  Thank you so much for your help.